# Using data with low variance in Mahalanobis

Tags: classification, variance, covariance-matrix

This question is in regard to a Mahalanobis Classifier. Where an unknown observation is compared to multiple different classes and the class with the smallest Mahalanobis Distance is the class chosen.

But, some parts (variables/columns) of my data have very little variance or sometimes even constants. Since the covariance Matrix is invariant to constants i'm rank deficient. These parts of the data hold critical information about the class. One class my have a constant there and the other my not or have a completely different constant. The data is useful for classification.

Just to give a simple example here is a made up data set for a couple classes to illustrate.

Class 1:

Observation 1: [127, 122, 120, 115, 135, 135, 135, 135, 145, 120, 133]

Observation 2: [118, 110, 108, 115, 135, 135, 135, 135, 138, 125, 130]

Class 2:

Observation 1: [255, 255, 255, 140, 145, 118, 116, 120, 145, 200, 205]

Observation 2: [255, 255, 255, 134, 140, 120, 119, 135, 150, 210, 199]

Say class 1 has constants or very little change for indexes 4-7 and class 2 has constants for indexes 0-2. And the rest has a normal distribution with enough variance. These constant ranges gives clear information as to the difference between class 1 and class 2.

If I include these constant ranges when I compute the means and inverse covariance matrices for Mahalanobis, assuming I don't get singular matrix error, which I don't, I'll will end up with massive Mahalanobis distances overflowing my 32bit limit.

**The question:**
Is there a way to include this data so it's meaningful? Or is this a fundamental limitation to the Mahalanobis Distance?

My current method is to just remove these ranges from the data entirely, but the data is critical for classification. I even tried removing all constants in those ranges but one and it still gives undesirable results.

Other thoughts:

1) I could run the data through a smoothing filter to make the data less "square wave" like.

2) The exact constant in the ranges are not critical. As long as all observations in the class have roughly +-10 maybe in that range. I was thinking about forcing variance in those regions. Change each observation randomly in those ranges.